# Rails でbundle install時に、Your Ruby version is 2.3.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1　とエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails

bundle install実行時に以下のエラーが返ってきます

> Your Ruby version is 2.3.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1

rubyのバージョン等は以下の通りです

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin18]
$ which bundler 
/usr/local/bin/bundler
$ which ruby
/Users/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

原因わかりますでしょうか？

**追記**

`gem install bundler`を実行したところ、以下のエラーが出ました。

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/CHANGELOG.md
```

原因を調べていますがハマっています。
解決策をご教示いただけると幸甚です。

Comment: 次の２つのコマンドの結果を教えてください。`which gem`, `rbenv version`。この質問に追記して頂ければ。

Comment: 以下の結果となっております。
`which gem
/Users/user/.rbenv/shims/gem`


`rbenv version
2.5.1 (set by /Users/user/src/.ruby-version)`

Comment: 回答に追記しました。

Answer (score 2):

[Ruby version is 2.3.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.0とエラーが出てしまう | teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/139925)

恐らく↑と同じ現象が起こっているかと思われます。具体的には以下の通りです。

- `which bundler`で`/usr/local/bin/bundler`と表示されるので、システムにインストールされているbundlerを呼び出している
- `bundle install`時にシステムにインストールされているRuby(恐らくversion2.3.7)を呼び出してGemfileが必要としているversionと差異があるためエラー

対策としては、

`gem install bundler`

としてrbenvのruby gemにbundlerをインストール&そのbundlerを用いるようにすればよいかと思われます。

---

**2019/01/13 追記**

`gem install bundler`で`Permissino denied`と怒られていることから、bundlerをシステムの方へインストールしようとしているのではないかと思われます。

一旦
`rbenv global 2.5.1`
をしてから、再度`gem install bundler`を実行してみては如何でしょうか。

それでもうまくかない場合は…`rbenv`をインストールし直すことをお勧めします。